# Modify results of django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have two models `Event` and `Shift`.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class Shift(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    start = models.TimeField()
    end = models.TimeField()
```

Now on some `view` I have to filter out `Events` that occur in the interval of a `Shift`. And I did this.

```
queryset = Event.objects.all()
queryset = queryset.filter(start__time__gte=s.start).filter(start__time__lte=s.end) |\
queryset.filter(start__time__lte=s.start).filter(end__time__gte=s.start)
```

And now I want to trim `start` and `end` of `events` in the `queryset` to be in the rage of the `start` and `end` of the `Shift` I'm filtering on. Also, some `events` may cross a `Shift` more than once. In that case, I have to split the `Event` to the number of times it crosses a `Shift`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Only in the queryset, or in the database?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Only in the queryset

Comment: Furthermore the query looks strange, if you specify a range, it is possible that nor the `start__time`, nor the `end_time` are in the range, but there is still overlap.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah I haven't seen that..